# I'm trying to create an image slider with modals and I'm having trouble with displaying my images

Tags: javascript, css, slider, carousel, coverflow

Im making a webpage using html, css and javascript. Im still new to all three. I have a sort of carousel image slider where when you click on an image, it expands to reveal more information. However, when the images in the slider and the additional content of the modals cannot appear at the same time. When the slider images are appearing, the modals disappear and only a blank overlay is shown and when the modals appear, the slider images disappear. As you can see in the screenshots, with the images commented, the models are working fine. Any suggestions would be appreciated. [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5K60.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCHDH.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.